# Need an explanation of this particular form action

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to understand how this sites form action works.

When I build a form I am always pointing the action to a file like

```
<form action="process.php" method="get" etc.....
```

On this particular site the form action is like this.

```
<form action="\search" method="get" etc....
```

Can someone explain where this action is pointing to or the reason why someone would have it this way?

Comment: There are prettified URL's in the project which means that you can point to the "shortcut" for the file which in this case might be search.html or search.php.

Comment: It is simply canonical naming.  Usually when you see canonical names the request is being routed to a page that will process based on the URL, session, cookie, etc. contents.  As Jay said, they are pretty URL's.  People remember keywords better than page names.

Answer (score 0):

First form will send the data to file `process.php`.

Second form will send the data to `\search` URL which can point to a specific file on your server depending on the rewrite that is done on the server.

The reason for the 2nd URL would be to increase search engine score.

Comment: NO it will have 0 effect on "search engine score"